# If else javascript statement

Tags: javascript, html

I have a code that i want to execute but dont know how to go about it. I have a page that you can convert between two languages, english and french. I want to run a script in my index.html.erb file only if the page is in french and not in English.

This code is at the beginning of my index.html.erb file.

```
<script>
  var a = <%= params[:locale]%>
  if(a == "fr")
  {
   <script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    var google_conversion_id = 1001007867;
    /* ]]> */
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
  </script>
  <noscript>
    <div style="display:inline;">
    </div>
  </noscript>
}
</script>
```

I am not sure if my code is correct. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have multiple `<script>` tags inside your first `<script>` tag, that is useless. You can just remove these as you are already working inside `<script>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

you cant nest script tags, you could append a script tag if your condition is met, sth. like :

```
<script>
var a = <%= params[:locale]%>;
console.log(a) /* THIS REALLY LOGS THE EXPECTED VALUE ? */
if(a == "fr")
{
     var google_conversion_id = 1001007867;
     var bh = document.createElement('script'), s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     bh.type = 'text/javascript';
     bh.src = '//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js';
     s.parentNode.insertBefore(bh, s);

}
</script>
  <noscript>
    <div style="display:inline;">
    </div>
  </noscript>
```

the better solutions would be if your templating-language e.g `<%= %>` supports if else conditions

check your browser console for errors

Comment: Why have you enclosed code under `if` statement in `IIFE` ?

Comment: @Kelsadita copy-paste youre right its not necessery, updated answer

Comment: `var a = <%= params[:locale]%>` is most likely an error

Comment: yes its rails. And it will return to me the language. I need to run the script just the way it is. So is there a way to run it in html? Its a script to track google conversion on the page.

Comment: well the way i answered the google-script will be inserted if your locale is "fr" and it will run ... what problem are you facing ?

Comment: what about the part for <noscript> <div display:inline>? sorry im a novice when it comes to javascript

Comment: you can put it right under the script tag, the content of a noscript tag is displayed if a user has javascript deactivated, so it makes no sense to have it inside a script tag, got it ?